# childIndex in full ExpandableListView?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have an ExpandableListView like;

```
Category1
 |
 |__ SubCategory1     -> index 0
 |
 |__ SubCategory2     -> index 1

Category2
 |
 |__ SubCategory1     -> index 2
 |
 |__ SubCategory2     -> index 3
 |
 |__ SubCategory3     -> index 4

Category3
 |
 |__ SubCategory1     -> index 5
```

I want get index values like shown at right side and link them with an ArrayList arrayList.get(indexValue)

How must i get indexValues like above?

Comment: you have to do a bit of math

Comment: Rows are creating dynamically. It can be possible, save all group's child counts and let do math to computer but i am searching better way.